# How to refresh the page but altering the params

Tags: javascript, refresh

I want to refresh my page, buy changing the param, if I execute this code:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    realoadCurrentURL()
});
```

If I execute only function `realoadCurrentURL()` this make the process with `document.location.search = url;` updating the param `toggloedIds` (that is an array) but this does not work with my `$(window).bind('beforeunload'...` function

I think this is made with a promise, but I want to fix it.

Thanks a lot!! everyone.

Comment: Not able to make out anything

Comment: I'm afraid the code block inside beforeunload callback will only take effect when you return a non-empty value.

Comment: Thanks I have to use localStorage instead